# Alguien me puede apoyar acerca de porqué los contadores no funcionan: "paciente", "síDona" y "noDona", en los métodos evaluarDatos y evaluarDonante

Tags: java, contador

```
   **En los últimos métodos creo que está el error, los métodos para evaluarDatos y
```

evaluarDonante son los que no hacen que se le sume 1 ni a paciente así como tampoco a síDona o a
noDona ¿Alguien me puede apoyar acerca de porqué los acomuladores no funcionan: variables "paciente", "síDona" y "noDona", es Netbeans con Java? No sé si deba implementarlo de forma diferente o si sólo debo modificar un poco los métodos que lo contienen, por favor**
Compila todo lo demás, pero no cuenta ni suma en la variable paciente y por lo tanto tampoco no hay valor para síDona o noDona

[image: Compila todo lo demás, pero no cuenta ni suma en la variable paciente y por lo tanto tampoco no hay valor para síDona o noDona]

---

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class PO1_U2_A2_DONANTES {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Bienvenid@");
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        datosPaciente pacient=new datosPaciente();//llamando a la clase con los métodos
        char opción, otroPaciente;
        
    do{
         System.out.println("a) Registro de personas");
         System.out.println("b) Reporte de pacientes que pueden o no donar");
         System.out.println("c) Salir");
         System.out.println("Elija que desea hacer:");
         opción = leer.next().charAt(0);
         
         switch(opción) {//puedo elegir entre 3 opciones
    case 'a':
        do {
        pacient.pedirDatos();
        pacient.mostrarDatos();
        pacient.evaluarDatos();
        pacient.evaluarDonante();
        System.out.println ("El paciente tiene los siguientes puntos: "+pacient.paciente);
        System.out.println ("Para ingresar los datos de otro paciente digite el número 1, si no digite el número 0");
        otroPaciente=leer.next().charAt(0);
       }while (otroPaciente=='1');
        break;
       
    case 'b':
      System.out.println("La cantidad de pacientes que puede donar es: "+ pacient.síDona);
        System.out.println("La cantidad de pacientes que no puede donar es: "+pacient.noDona);
        break;
        
    case 'c':
        System.out.println("¡Hasta pronto!");
        break;   }
         
      }while (opción !='c');     } 
}
```

aquí empieza la calse con los métodos

```
    import java.util.Scanner;// este paquete nos permite leer lo que se ecribe desde el teclado
    public class datosPaciente {
    String nombre;
            char género;
            byte edad;// la edad no es mayor a 127
            float peso;// El peso puede ser con decimales
            byte tensionDiastólica;//50-110
            short tensionSistólica;//
            byte pulso;
            int plaquetas;
            float hemoglobina;
            String ayunas;
            byte paciente;
            short síDona=0;
            short noDona=0;
    
       public void pedirDatos(){
       Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del paciente");
        nombre=leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digita 1 si el sexo del paciente es Femenino o 2 si es masculino");
        género=leer.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Ingresa la edad");
        edad=leer.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el peso");
        peso=leer.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la tensión diastólica");
        tensionDiastólica=leer.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la tensión Sistólica");
        tensionSistólica=leer.nextShort();
        System.out.println("Ingresa su frecuencia cardiaca");
        pulso=leer.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de las plaquetas en cc");
        plaquetas=leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el valor de la hemoglobina");
        hemoglobina=leer.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("¿Está en ayunas?");
        ayunas=leer.next();
        }
        
      public void mostrarDatos(){
        System.out.println("El nombre del paciente es: "+nombre);
        
        if (género=='1'){
        System.out.println("Su género es: femenino");}
        else if (género=='2'){System.out.println("Su género es: masculino");}
        
        System.out.println("Su edad es:"+ edad);
        System.out.println("Su peso es: "+ peso);
        System.out.println("Su tensión diastólica es: "+ tensionDiastólica);
        System.out.println("Su tensión Sistólica es: "+ tensionSistólica);
        System.out.println("El valor de las plaquetas es: "+ plaquetas);
        System.out.println("El valor de la hemoglobina es: "+ hemoglobina);
     switch (ayunas){
             case "sí":System.out.println("Y está en ayunas");break;
             case "no":System.out.println("Y no está en ayunas");break;
            }
     } 
          // JUSTO AQUÍ ES DONDE CREO QUE ESTÁ EL ERROR PORQUE NO LE SUMA NADA A "paciente"
       public void evaluarDatos(){
         if (edad>=18 && edad<=50){paciente=paciente ++;}
           
         if (peso>50){paciente=paciente ++;}
         
         if (tensionDiastólica >=50 && tensionDiastólica<=110){paciente=paciente ++;}
        
         if (tensionSistólica >=90 && tensionSistólica<=180){paciente=paciente ++;}
         
         if (plaquetas>150000){paciente=paciente ++;}
         
        if ((género== '1' && hemoglobina>12.5)||(género== '2' && hemoglobina>13.5))
          {paciente=paciente ++;} 
         
        if (ayunas=="no"){paciente=paciente ++;}
       }

       public void evaluarDonante(){
       if (paciente==7){síDona= síDona ++;}
       else if (paciente<7){noDona= noDona ++;}
        }  
    }
```

Comment: No es lo mismo `paciente = paciente++` que `paciente++` _a secas_ en Java. ¿Venís de C o C++?

Comment: Por cierto, procura evitar usar diacríticos (como tildes) en tu código. Y por sobre todo, aprende a fragmentar el problema por partes: prueba una y otra vez, y descarta qué problemas podrías estar teniendo. Lo que crees que funciona, puede que efectivamente no funcione :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Padaleiana, ya me di cuenta de que C++ y Java son diderentes. Gracias, ya revisé lo de los acentos y eso porque al leerlos no se ven las letras, y la forma de escribir el contador. Además de que ya ví que debía colocar en el método de evaluar el argumento de paciente y que la condición va entre paréntesis pero como son dos, cada una debe estar también en paréntesis: if ((edad>=18)&&(edad<=50)){ paciente ++;}